# VC Title and BarButtonItems not showing Swift

Tags: swift

I am having trouble showing the title and bar button item in my VC.
I don't mind if I am able to get it working as I have it now with a few tweaks vs rearranging things.

I made a simple dummy project to illustrate what I want.

[image]

The top right of the image shows what I originally had.
I was able to segue to it and it worked BUT the Title AND the bar button did not show. All that would show was a back button with the title of that VC as the back button text

The code I used for that was this

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
  if segue.identifier == "fromLandingToTBC" {    
     let tabVc = segue.destination as! UITabBarController  
     let navVc = tabVc.viewControllers!.first as! UINavigationController
     let destinationVC = navVc.viewControllers.first as! CardDetailsViewController
     destinationVC.cardID = selectedCard!
  }  
}
```

The VC on the bottom right is an idea I had. However I am not able to do a few things. First I am not able to add a bar button item even though there is a space for it. Second, I do not know how to do the code in the prepare for segue

I tried modifying the code I had to something like this

```
let tabVC = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
let destinationVC = tabVC.viewControllers!.first as! CardDetailsViewController
```

But it always crashes

Comment: Can you put the dummy project on Github?

Comment: Everything on the dummy project is in that screen shot...there's no code

Comment: I just created project to show clean idea of overview

Comment: Oh I c. The problem is that you have a root navigation controller on the left. That one will block the navigation bar of the top right one. Try to disable the nav bar of the first navigation controller. Or simply remove it.

Comment: I need that nav on that VC because it has bar button items...

Comment: But you can't have two nav bars at the same time. You need to disable the nav bar on the Tabview controller

Comment: @J.Wang im sorry if I'm not understanding you...I want the nav bar...I want the title and the buttons that I have added to show...right now the nav bar shows but nothing inside of it shows...

Comment: There are two navigation controllers right? And both of them have nav bar enabled. And the first one will actually block the second one if that makes sense. So if you want to have the second nav bar shown, then you need to disable the first one on the Tab bar view controller.

Comment: So I can't have a Nav controller on both?

Comment: Yes you can. Let's look at the VC with the button titled "START". This one will have nav bar from the first navigation controller. And if you disable the navigation bar on the tab bar controller then the top right vc will have nav bar from the second navigation controller. Does it make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134657/discussion-between-rubberducky4444-and-j-wang).

Comment: Your first problem is showing tabBarController. It's wrong. Because tabBarController has a tab bar not the navigation bar. Therefore you should not showing up the tabBarController when you're pressing start button from your initial VC. Try to present instead of show or show detail. I mean connections of the VC, between FirstVC and TabBarController. When call the "show" as segue connection and VC going to be pushed. And pushed VC must have a "Back" button by default. Remember the UITabBarController much like to UINavigationController, and they used for navigating between UIViewControllers

Comment: @Mannopson if you want to put that as answer I will mark it correct, solved it

Comment: Also don't use prepareForSegue method as you provided. They're gives you only crashes and not anything else